# Is it a good idea to set the TTL value of the dns to 15 day for a static ip to reduce the dns queries?

Tags: dns-hosting, google-cloud-platform

To reduce the number of dns queries(30 Million dns queries / month for a 24 hr TTL value) why not set the TTL value to 15 days since in my case the vm(google-compute cloud) host ip is static and no plans to change the vm(google cloud). If the vm has to be changed in the future then my plan is to reset the TTL value to lowest value as possible and wait for 15 days and then change the dns record to point to the new vm's ip. Is there any flaw with this approach ?

Answer (score 1):

> If the vm has to be changed in the future then my plan is to reset the TTL value to lowest value as possible and wait for 15 days and then change the dns record to point to the new vm's ip.

That works for planned changes.

> Is there any flaw with this approach ?

The problem is unplanned changes. Can/will google gaurantee that you can continue using that IP address even if the hardware asssociated with your VM dies? can you gaurantee that you won't have a dispute with googling that causes them to suddently terminate your service? If you are the target of a DDOS can google/will google redirect traffic targetted at your IP to a server (or group of servers) that is beefy enough to seperate the attack traffic from the legitimate traffic?

If the worst happens and you lose the ability to use the IP can you afford to be down (from the perspective of some users) for 15 days?